# Client blocks on recv while server sends data continuously (socket / C++)

Tags: c++, sockets

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Have a server running on a Linux VM machine (code below).
- A Winsock client that:

  - sends a request to download a file
  - receives the data for the requested file

Once the server has received the request, it sends the data continuously (using `write`) until the file's content has been sent. The file I am trying to download here is 284678 bytes in chunks of 2kB. The server first write, is a header in the form of a sudo HTTP request that contains a Content-Length property. So I know the file size the client is about to download. The rest is self-explanatory in the code.

## Problem:

- If I sent the client socket blocking (default), what happens most of the times (not all the times - sometimes it works) is that the client starts to get the data fine and then eventually blocks on `recv` (it blocks close to the end) after the server has (I guess) sent all the data. The output is like this:

```
Ready to read data!
Ready to read data!
Read so far 2048/284678 (2048)
Ready to read data!
Read so far 4096/284678 (2048)
Ready to read data!
...
Read so far 282570/284678 (2048)
Ready to read data!
Read so far 282754/284678 (184)
Ready to read data!
Read so far 282840/284678 (86)
Ready to read data! << BLOCK HERE
```

on the server side:

```
Sending 2048 / total: 280576
2048
Sending 2048 / total: 282624
2048
Sending 2048 / total: 284672
2048
Sending 6 / total: 284678
6
```

- if I set the client socket non-blocking, it gets stuck into an infinite `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` loop (same, towards the end of the download).

I need to do something better, obviously (due to my lack of knowledge of socket - which I am trying to learn as a part of a summer project). It drives me crazy as I think I encountered this problem before but can't remember how to fix it?

- I obviously dont understand how `write`/`recv` here works whether in the context of blocking or non-blocking client-socket. So the code is malformed.
- Sending data continuously from the server without checking if the client has received the data first is not good. The client should acknowledge the server has received the packet before the server sends a new one. That seems inefficient to me, and surely the socket process would make this possible without this constant back-and-forth notification process?

I would appreciate help with this very much.

### Edit:

I tried to increase the buffer size (to 65356) with no difference. The problem remains. Now, what I ended up thinking is that the client "blocks" on recv because the server has stopped sending data to the client (it finished sending sending the data before the server did get it all). So the socket is not readable on the client side, hence the blocking. If I artificially keep sending data from the server after it has sent all the file data like so:

```
 while ((bytes_read = ifs.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE).gcount()) > 0) {
   total_send += bytes_read;
   std::cerr << "Sending " << bytes_read << " / total: " << total_send << std::endl;
   //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
   int err = write(events[i].data.fd, buffer, bytes_read);
   std::cerr << err << std::endl;
 }
 while (1) {
   // wait until client has all the data?
   write(events[i].data.fd, buffer, 4096);
 }
```

Then eventually, the client manages to get to the end of the download process (get all the data until `total_bytes_received == desired_data_size`). Yet the data I got is not correct because it seems that what's recv in the end is the rubbish data i keep sending. Does it mean the only way I get this working is by sending a message to the server from the client, every time I am supposed to read a packet? so that the server doesn't overload the client with data? (the server should not send the next packet until the first one has been read by the client).

### Server Code (running on Linux vm).

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

#include <csignal>

constexpr int MAX_EVENTS = 10;
constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

int server_socket;

void SignalHandler(int signum)
{
        std::cerr << "\rclosing server socket (" << server_socket << ") after ctrl+c signal received" << std::endl;
        close(server_socket);
        exit(signum);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler);

        int client_socket;
        sockaddr_in server_addr{}, client_addr{};
        socklen_t client_addr_size;
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        if ((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
                perror("failed to create socket");
                return -1;
        }

        int reuse_addr = 1;
        if (setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_addr, sizeof(reuse_addr)) == -1) {
                std::cerr << "failed to set SO_REUSEADDR option." << std::endl;
                close(server_socket);
                return -1;
        }

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(xxxx);
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        if (bind(server_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
                perror("failed to bind socket");
                return -1;
        }

        if (listen(server_socket, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
                perror("failed to listen for connections");
                return -1;
        }

        int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
        if (epoll_fd == -1) {
                perror("failed to create epoll instance");
                return -1;
        }

        epoll_event event{};
        event.data.fd = server_socket;
        event.events = EPOLLIN;
        if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, server_socket, &event) == -1) {
                perror("failed to add server socket to epoll");
                return -1;
        }

        std::vector<epoll_event> events(MAX_EVENTS);

        int counter = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> file_list = {"corgi.png", "alien.png"};

        while(true) {
                int num_events = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events.data(), MAX_EVENTS, -1);
                if (num_events == -1) {
                        perror("failed to wait for events");
                        return -1;
                }
                std::cout << "waiting..." << std::endl;
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_events; ++i) {
                        if (events[i].data.fd == server_socket) {
                                // accept new client connection
                                client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
                                client_socket = accept(server_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&client_addr), &client_addr_size);
                                if (client_socket == -1) {
                                        perror("failed to accept client connection");
                                        return -1;
                                }

                                std::cout << "New client connected: " << inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr) << std::endl;

                                // add new client socket to the epoll event list
                                event.data.fd = client_socket;
                                event.events = EPOLLIN;
                                if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client_socket, &event) == -1) {
                                        perror("failed to add client socket to epoll");
                                        return -1;
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                // read data from client socket
                                ssize_t bytes_read = read(events[i].data.fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
                                if (bytes_read == -1) {
                                        perror("failed to read from client socket");
                                        return -1;
                                }
                                if (bytes_read == 0) {
                                        // client disconnected
                                        std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl;
                                        close(events[i].data.fd);
                                }
                                else {
                                        std::string request = std::string(buffer, bytes_read);
                                        std::cout << "Received data from client: " << request << std::endl;
                                        if (request.find("GET / HTTP/1.1") != std::string::npos) {
                                                std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                                                                                           "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
                                                   "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
                                                                                           "<p>I have been called " + std::to_string(++counter) + " times already</p>";
                                                write(events[i].data.fd, response.c_str(), response.size());
                                        }
                                        else if (request.find("GET /filelist") != std::string::npos) {
                                                std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                                                                                           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"
                                                                                           "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS\r\n"
                                                                                           "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type\r\n"
                                                                                           "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n";
                                                for (const auto& file: file_list)
                                                        response += file + "\n";
                                                write(events[i].data.fd, response.c_str(), response.size());
                                        }
                                        else if (request.find("GET /filedownload?") != std::string::npos) {
                                                size_t request_header_len = strlen("GET /filedownload?");
                                                std::string url = std::string(request, request_header_len, request.size() - request_header_len);
                                                /*
                                                ** (?=&|\\s|$): the match stops at the next occurrence of an ampersand (&),
                                                ** a whitespace character (\\s), or the end of the string ($). This is necessary
                                                ** because the request is "/downloadfile?file=a.txt&file=b.txt HTTP/1.1". So
                                                ** we don't want the HTTP/1.1 as part of the value for the last key-value pair
                                                ** in the argument list.
                                                */
                                                std::regex pattern("file=([^&\\s]+)(?=&|\\s|$)");
                                                std::sregex_iterator iter(url.begin(), url.end(), pattern);
                                                std::sregex_iterator end;
                                                std::vector<std::string> requested_file_list;
                                                while (iter != end) {
                                                        std::smatch match = *iter;
                                                        std::cerr << match[0].str() << "Requested file: " << match[1].str() << std::endl;
                                                        requested_file_list.push_back(match[1].str());
                                                        ++iter;
                                                }
                                                if (requested_file_list.size() == 0)
                                                        continue;

                                                bool file_exist = (std::find(file_list.begin(),
                                                        file_list.end(), requested_file_list[0]) != file_list.end());

                                                if (!file_exist)
                                                        continue;

                                                std::cerr << "=----------------------------------------" << std::endl;
                                                std::cerr << "Requested file " << requested_file_list[0] << std::endl;
                                                std::cerr << "=----------------------------------------" << std::endl;
                                                std::ifstream ifs(requested_file_list[0].c_str(), std::ios::binary);
                                                ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
                                                std::streampos file_size = ifs.tellg();
                                                std::cerr << "content length: " << file_size << std::endl;
                                                ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

                                                std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                                                                                           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"
                                                                                           "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS\r\n"
                                                                                           "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type\r\n"
                                                                                           "Content-Type: application/octect-stream\r\n"
                                                                                           "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(file_size) + "\r\n\r\n";

                                                write(events[i].data.fd, response.c_str(), response.size());
                                                char buffer[2048];
                                                size_t bytes_read;
                                                int total_send = 0;
                                                while ((bytes_read = ifs.read(buffer, 2048).gcount()) > 0) {
                                                        total_send += bytes_read;
                                                        std::cerr << "Sending " << bytes_read << " / total: " << total_send << std::endl;
                                                        int err = write(events[i].data.fd, buffer, bytes_read);
                                                        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
                                                }
                                                //shutdown(client_socket, SD_SEND);
                                                ifs.close();
                                        }
                                        //close(client_socket);
                                        // process data or send a response to the client
                                }
                        }

                }
        }

        close(server_socket);

        return 0;
}
```

### Client code: (windows)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

//#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#endif

#define MAX_CHUNK_SIZE 2048

class TcpClientSocketWin {
public:
    TcpClientSocketWin() {
        // just a basic setup
        WSADATA wsa_data;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa_data);

        socket_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        
        // Set the socket to non-blocking mode
        unsigned long non_blocking = 1;
        ioctlsocket(socket_, FIONBIO, &non_blocking);

        const char* server_ip = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        int server_port = xxxx;
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr{};
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, server_ip, &(server_addr.sin_addr));
        
        // Initiate the connection
        int connect_result = connect(socket_, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr));
        if (connect_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
            if (error_code != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                // Handle connection error
                std::cerr << "Error while connecting to the server " << error_code << std::endl;
                //return TaskResult{std::nullopt, "Error while connecting to the server"};
            }
        }
        
        // Wait until the connection is established
        fd_set write_fds;
        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
        FD_SET(socket_, &write_fds);

        timeval timeout{};
        timeout.tv_sec = 10; // Set an appropriate timeout value
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        int select_result = select(socket_ + 1, nullptr, &write_fds, nullptr, &timeout);
        if (select_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "Error while waiting for the connection to be established " << select_result << std::endl; 
        } else if (select_result == 0) {
            // Connection timeout
            std::cerr << "Connection timed out" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    ~TcpClientSocketWin() {
        closesocket(socket_);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    void PerformRequest(const std::string& filename = "") {
                
        std::string request = "GET /filedownload?file=" + filename + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
        const char* request_data = request.c_str();
        int request_size = static_cast<int>(request.size());
        int bytes_sent = 0;
        while (bytes_sent < request_size) {
            int result = send(socket_, request_data + bytes_sent, request_size - bytes_sent, 0);
            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
                if (error_code == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                    // The socket is non-blocking, and the send operation would block.
                    // You can perform other tasks here, if needed.
                    std::cerr << "WSAEWOULDBLOCK" << std::endl;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    // Handle send error
                    std::cerr << "Error while sending data" << std::endl;
                }
            } else if (result == 0) {
                // The connection has been closed by the server.
                break;
            }

            // Data is sent successfully
            bytes_sent += result;
        }

        // read the response
        std::vector<char> buffer;
        std::string response;
        int total_size = 0;
        int read_so_far = 0;
        while (1) {
            
            char chunk[MAX_CHUNK_SIZE];
            std::cerr << "Ready to read data!" << std::endl;
            int chunk_size = recv(socket_, chunk, MAX_CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
            if (chunk_size == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
                if (error_code == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                    std::cerr << "WSAEWOULDBLOCK " << read_so_far << std::endl;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "Error while reading from the socket" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            // we are requesting the response to contain ContentLength in the header
            // regardless of the type of data type (json or binary or ...) so that
            // a single version of the code can address all request types.
            if (total_size == 0) {
                total_size = GetContentLength(std::string(chunk, chunk_size));
                assert(total_size != 0); // well a file could have 0 file size!?
                //std::cerr << "File Size: " << total_size << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                buffer.insert(buffer.end(), chunk, chunk + chunk_size);
                read_so_far += chunk_size;
                int progress = (read_so_far * 100) / total_size;
                std::cerr << "Read so far " << read_so_far << "/" << total_size << " (" << chunk_size << ")" << std::endl;
                if (read_so_far >= total_size) {
                    std::cerr << "\rBreaking\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
private:
    int GetContentLength(const std::string& header) {
        std::size_t content_length_pos = header.find("Content-Length:");
        assert(content_length_pos != std::string::npos); // should handle that properly I know)
        content_length_pos += strlen("Content-Length:");
        std::size_t end_of_line_pos = header.find("\r\n", content_length_pos);
        std::string content_length_asstr = header.substr(
            content_length_pos, end_of_line_pos - content_length_pos);

        return std::stoi(content_length_asstr);
    }

    SOCKET socket_;
};

int main() {
    TcpClientSocketWin tcp_client_socket_win;
 
    tcp_client_socket_win.PerformRequest("corgi.png");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify properly how much data you want to read. If you ask for a huge chuck while getting just a few bytes, it won't necessarily return from `recv`.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Like so 
`int total_bytes_received  = 0;
while (total_bytes_received < desired_data_size) {
    int remaining_bytes = desired_data_size - total_bytes_received;
    chunk_size = recv(socket_, chunk, std::min(remaining_bytes, MAX_CHUNK_SIZE), 0);`

? Btw in my test it seems to work (hear emoji insert here). If this works, I would accept this as an answer, as I have not see this anywhere else (though recommended by some people).

Comment: yeah, this should work.

Comment: Sadly no this doesn't work. I had a sleep_for on the server to slow down the server. I still have the issue if I remove that;  the server is sending data too quickly to the client. And the client is not keeping up.

Comment: this is a different story. Try asking again about improving efficiency. Your reading code might be too slow or you send too much data on the network. Reading 2kb per `recv` call and then parsing and printing stuff is not efficient. Also network bandwith can be limited, you cannot send too much data.

Comment: @ALX23z increasing the buffer didn't solve the problem. The problem is that outband is much greater than the inband probably. And yet I believe this is a common problem so surely it has to be handled in production code. See my edit below where I suggest that if the server keeps sending "rubbish" data after it has sent the file data, then the client can keep reading the data until eventually `total_bytes_received == desired_data_size`. This seems to indicate that the client blocks on `recv` when I don't do so because the socket is not readable any longer (since the server has stopped sending).

Comment: This is a non-standard non-portable way of determining file size: `std::streampos file_size = ifs.tellg();`.  Maybe use `stat` or `fstat` instead.  Have you verified that the Content-Length header has the correct value?  Have you verified that the client counts starting at the correct byte?

Comment: You've spent so much time worrying about blocking that I guess you never checked to see if the first dozen bytes in your file were correct.  They aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're discarding the beginning of the data, that was received in the same `recv()` call as the "header".  Because you discard part of the data, the part you do keep never reaches the total expected size.

Find the end of the header inside your receive buffer, and use whatever data follows to initialize your file-content vector.

You seem to be operating on the assumption that one `recv()` call gives data from exactly one `send()` call.  That is not how byte-oriented stream sockets (like TCP) work.

Comment: I will check again) but I did check at some point that the first recv was getting the exact same number of bytes than the header size, and that therefore I didn't need to seperate the header from the data, but I will check again.

Comment: @user18490: That may happen by accident (and is influenced by timing, so if your server delays between sending the header and the first batch of file content, it could even happen a majority of the time) but TCP does not preserve any message boundaries and you should be prepared for a recv to return with less than a whole message or parts of multiple messages.

Comment: I owe you an apology. I will gat half a blame please) because I did think about checking, but then when I did check, I was lucky enough to find the same number on both ends so I discarded that as the problem, but yes of course, regardless of the number this should have been absolutely implemented. So for future reference in case someone wants to know you need to do: `int already_read = std::max(0, chunk_size - 210); if (already_read > 0) buffer.insert(buffer.end(), chunk + 210, chunk + already_read);" in the client side. I have just hard-coded the header size here for a quick test.